# A tool like Jenkins, but not focused on Software: General Job Executor

Tags: linux, server

I search a tool for **general job execution**

Features:

- Web GUI
- Start Jobs from templates
- Start individual jobs
- Multi-Host: Jobs should be able to get executed on remote hosts.
- History of Jobs: start-date, started-by, output, host, end-date.
- Manual and sheduled job starting.
- Scale: We have only about 100 hosts and 15 users
- Licence: open source
- Server OS: Linux only

For Continuous Integration we use Jenkins. But it focuses too much on software development.

Comment: This any help? http://alternativeto.net/software/jenkins/

Comment: What is it that you need to do?  We use Jenkins for a CI build, but, for other tasks also.